# FaunaDB as redis/ssdb replacement?

Tags: redis, faunadb

We did hear about FaunaDB product on one of [a recent meetup](https://www.meetup.com/publiccloudpl/events/239332690/) :) by Maciej Winnicki from Serverless. [Presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/mthenw/the-state-of-serverless-pcug)

We take it into consideration. Could  FaunaDB be a replacement of the SSDB that we are currently using (as a replacement of Redis)? Changing our current api is an option.

We are expecting a 500GB-1TB of data that we would like to cache, but hopefully without sharding. SSDB supposed to be a great Redis replacement, since it can dump part of the cache into a disk (we do not need extremely fast cache, and just % of the data is used frequently, the rest could be released from the memory).

Unfortunately, SSDB's nodes happens to get out_of_sync during heavy writes, and we did already use parameters greater that SSDB developers suggest. Currently the sync delay of 60-100s is acceptable in our use-case, but a node getting out_of_sync require a manual fix - so [we have to look around for other solutions.](https://github.com/ideawu/ssdb/issues/1045)

Sharding with redis seems inevitable, but maybe Faunadb could solve it?

One remark - we prefer to keep the data close to our services (not to pay AWS data transfers) so it should be installed on our servers. Additionally, the price is an important factor - adding Redis with sharding to our stack, is a reasonable cost and workload - so FaunaDB should be competitive to this scenario.

How do you see our case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FaunaDB does all data distribution for you, so you won't need to worry about sharding. [Queries run in transactions, so you always see a consistent view of your data.](https://fauna.com/blog/distributed-consistency-at-scale-spanner-vs-calvin)

It's not clear what query patterns you are using, but FaunaDB's query language can match most of the Redis features. [Learn about the language here.](https://fauna.com/documentation/queries)

The easiest way to get started is by [signing up for FaunaDB Serverless Cloud, which is free](https://fauna.com/sign-up) to get stated with, and pay-per-request when you are in production. We also offer enterprise licenses for running on-premise if you have particular deployment requirements.

When you are ready to import your data for the first time, we have an import tool that might be useful. Also, a whole lot of [client libraries on github.](https://github.com/fauna)

Answer (score -1):

SSDB's binlog size is define as `20 * 1000 * 1000`.

[Github](https://github.com/ideawu/ssdb/blob/5242b0c5d8dfe2f48deb7210803b26f9f968ed8b/src/ssdb/options.cpp#L10)

You can change it and rebulid your SSDB.